block I GET Compute Budget: SetComputeUnitLimit DEDUCTIN FROM EVERY TRANSACTION
Compute Budget
ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111
Instruction Data Raw
030417010000000000
Input Args
{2 items
discriminator:{2 items
type:
"u8"
data:
3
}
microLamports:{2 items
type:
"u64"
data:
71428
}Compute Budget
ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111
Instruction Data Raw
030417010000000000
Input Args
{2 items
discriminator:{2 items
type:
"u8"
data:
3
}
microLamports:{2 items
type:
"u64"
data:
71428
}
